# Regrouping all phrases in bold in a Latex document

Tags: table-of-contents

I have to write lots of lengthy reports and at the end of each one I make a page synthesizing all the results/main lines of the document. During the writing phase of all chapters, I put these relevant information in bold.

My question is: is there a way to have a function that  `grep`s all the `\textbf{}` content in my entire document and put it in a single page at the end of my document? Something similar to `\listoffigures`, but more like `\listofmyimportantinformation`-kind of thing?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is to create an external file which is included (automatically) at the end.

If you don't want automatic inclusion, you will want to comment out the `\AtEndDocument` part and create a command like
`\def\listofmyimportantinformation{\@input{"\jobname.bflist.tex"}}`.

---

**Solution 1**

*Using a dedicated command*

The following solution uses a dedicated command rather than `\textbf`
to mark the important stuff.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newfile}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \newoutputstream{importantlist}
  \openoutputfile{"\jobname.importantlist.tex"}{importantlist}}

\def\listofmyimportantstuff{%
  \closeoutputstream{importantlist}
  \section{The Following Stuffs are Important}
  \@input{"\jobname.importantlist.tex"}}
\makeatother  

\def\importantstuff#1{%
  \textbf{#1}
  \addtostream{importantlist}{\textbf{#1}}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\importantstuff{This is important}

\lipsum[2]

\importantstuff{\textsf{Also this one is}}

\listofmyimportantstuff

\end{document}
```

---

**Solution 2**

*Using the `\textbf` command*

Please be warned that this solution deviates from best practices. Once you redefine the `\textbf` command,  it can have unintended consequences since that command is most likely to be used internally or in places where you would not want that to appear in that list of 
important stuffs.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newfile}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \newoutputstream{bflist}
  \openoutputfile{"\jobname.bflist.tex"}{bflist}}
\AtEndDocument{%
  \closeoutputstream{bflist}
  \@input{"\jobname.bflist.tex"}}
\makeatother  


\renewcommand{\textbf}[1]{{\bfseries#1}\addtostream{bflist}{{\bfseries#1}}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\textbf{This text is in bold.}

\lipsum[2]

\textbf{\textsf{Another text in bold.}}


\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 But it might be helpful to warn that redefining `\textbf` in this way can have unintended consequences if that command is used internally or in places where you would not want to add to the output stream (e.g. table header).  A much safer method would be to use dedicated markup for the important stuff rather than redefining `\textbf`.

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes, in fact using a dedicated markup for the important stuff could have been much easier. But the OP did seem to be in a situation where there are already many '\textbf`'s , and converting them to some dedicated command would mean a bit too much work. But again, I must say, if I were in a situation like this, I would use a dedicated command. Do you want me reflect the contents of your comment in my answer? Thanks.

Comment: It's up to you whether to edit the question, but I think that it's helpful for others to always try to show best practices rather than simply answer what people ask.   So I would show a proper markup solution and give your redefinition as a last resort in the answer. :)

Comment: indeed, I had already a lot of `\textbf`s in the main text, but I just replaced all of them by \importantstuff{}. It works exactly as I wanted to. Thank you very much.